# Connection pool sqlalchemy always return a cached result

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, connection-pooling

I use the following code to create connection pooling and run SQL query.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
                f'mysql+pymysql://{usr}:{pw}@{db_config["host"]}:{db_config["port"]}/'
                f'{sub_db}', pool_size=24, max_overflow=40, poolclass=pool.QueuePool)
connection = engine.connect()
pandas.read_sql(sql=my_query, con=connection)
```

However, I found that connection I created sometime returns a cached DB return:

E.g. I run SQL function `validatePW` to validate tokens based on a DB table.  I have two users: **A** and **B** with different passwords.  User **A**'s password is 'PW1'.
If I run `pandas.read_sql(sql="select validatePW('A', 'PW1')", con=connection)`, I got a `True` return which is as expected.  and if I first run `pandas.read_sql(sql="select validatePW('B', 'PW1')", con=connection)`, I will get a `False` return (**B**'s password is not 'PW1').

Now if I run these two queries sequentially, the results will become funny

```
pd.read_sql(sql="select validatePW('A', 'PW1')", con=connection)
pd.read_sql(sql="select validatePW('B', 'PW1')", con=connection)
```

I will get two `True` return, although I am expecting the second query would return a `False`.  It seems like connection is returning a cached result from the previous run.  Why is that?  Is there anyway to avoid it? Thanks

Comment: How is validatePW declared?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, `validatePW` is a database function.  When I call this function outside Python, I always got desired results. `validatePW` simply does the comparison and does not save any cache

Comment: Did you run it consecutively like you have done in python?

Comment: The other change I can recommend is to try parametrising the values used in the query.

Comment: You could try committing (or rolling back) the connection between calls.  If that works it might be worth sharing the function code (or a [mre]) so we can understand what is happening.

Comment: @snakecharmerb, Yes, auto-commit option is default ON when I saw this weird issue

Comment: @OluwafemiSule, Yes, they are run consecutively